# How to redirect to a blade dashboard page from Vue login Component page after successfully login in laravel JetStream?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-jetstream

I created a laravel 8 project using jetstream authentication. As stack I have used inertia+vue. After successful login, I need to redirect to a blade file. But the problem is when I redirect to the blade file, the blade file opens as a modal like the image attached below. And the URL doesn't change (I mean the browser doesn't get refreshed). I would be grateful if you can suggest me the solution. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I eventually found this that allowed me to redirect to a page directly from a controller without it appearing in a modal—[https://inertiajs.com/redirects#external-redirects.](https://inertiajs.com/redirects#external-redirects)

Example:

```
return Inertia::location($url);
```